# Check if all letters of the alphabet appear in a file with no repeats

Tags: c, arrays, loops, csv

I'm writing a program that needs to read a CSV file and check that all letters in the alphabet appear one time on each side of the comma. The file would look something like this:

```
a,x
b,j
c,g
d,l
e,s
f,r
g,u
h,z
i,w
j,c
k,e
l,a
m,v
```

but there would be 26 lines total. What would be the most efficient way to check that each side has all 26 letters with no repeats?

Comment: By using an array to flag their occurrence. Or, as there are 26 different values, a 32-bit `int` with 1 bit to represent each value (if in lowercase letter range). If all letters are present the value will be `0x3FFFFFF`.

Comment: What exactly is the part you have problems with? Reading a file? Parsing CSV data? Choosing a data structure to put the data in? Finding an appropriate algorithm to solve the "unique letter" problem?

Comment: What's your definition of efficient?

Comment: Use a frequency array. Declare an array with 128 elements (one for each possible ASCII character) initialized to all zero, and read the file character-by-character incrementing the corresponding element each time a character is read, e.g. `char freq[128] = {0};` then while reading `int c; while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF) freq[c]++;` When done, loop over your array, e.g. `for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) if (freq[i] == 1) /* output char occurred once */` Do the same for `'A'` to `'Z'` if you want single occurrence upper-case.

Comment: "I'm writing a program" --> post that partial program to add clarity and narrow the scope.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why `freq[128]` versus `freq[UCHAR_MAX+1]`, so `freq[(unsigned char) c]` works for all `c`?

Comment: @chux What -- and un-violate my own rule about no *magic-numbers*... I guess someone needs to save me from myself on occasion, sage advice again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is unclear from your question and follow-up comments where exactly you are stuck, or whether you have thrown in the towel and given up, let's take it from the beginning.

**Open Your File (or reading `stdin`)**

Before you can do anything with the content of your file, you need to open you file for reading. For reading formatted-input you will generally use the functions that read and write from a file stream using a `FILE *` stream pointer (as opposed to the low-level *file-descriptor* file interface). To open your file, you will call `fopen` and *check the* ***return*** to validate the open succeeded.

Do not hard-code filenames or numbers in your program. Your program takes arguments, either pass the filename to open as an argument, or prompt for entry of the filename. You can increase the flexibility of your program by taking the filename to read as an argument, or read from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided (as most Linux utilities do). Since `stdin` is a file stream, you can simply assign it to your `FILE*` pointer if you are not opening a filename provided as an argument. For example:

```
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (argc > 1)               /* if one argument provided */
        fopen (argv[1], "r");   /* open file with name from argument */
    else
        fp = stdin;             /* set fp to stdin */

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

which can be shortened using the *ternary* operator, e.g.:

```
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
```

**Reading Your Data**

With a file-stream open and ***validated***, you can now read your data from your file. While you could read with `fscanf`, you are limited in the information it provides in the event less that two values are read. Additionally, reading with the `scanf` family of functions is full of pitfalls due to what characters remain in your input file-stream depending on the conversion specifiers used and on whether the conversion succeeded or failed. Nonetheless, a simple approach that validates two conversions took place according to your *format-string* will allow you to read your file, e.g.

```
    char c1, c2;    /* characters from each line */
    int freq1[MAXC] = {0}, freq2[MAXC] = {0};   /* frequency arrays */
    ...
    while (fscanf (fp, " %c, %c", &c1, &c2) == 2)   /* read all chars */
        if (c1 > 0 || c2 > 0)   /* validate ASCII values */
            /* increment element in each */
            freq1[(unsigned char)c1]++, freq2[(unsigned char)c2]++;
```

(the downside is any variation in format on one line can leave you with unwanted characters stored, and if less than two conversions take place, your read loop stops despite valid data remaining unread)

A better approach is to read a line-at-a-time with a *line-oriented* input function such as `fgets` or POSIX `getline`. With this approach, you are consuming a line of data at a time, and then parsing the needed information from the stored line. The benefits are significant. You have an independent validation of the read itself, and then whether you find the needed values in the line. If your format varies an you parse less than the needed values from the line, you have the option of simply skipping that line and continuing with the next. Further, what remains in your input file stream does not depend on the conversion specifiers used.

An example with `fgets` and `sscanf` doing the same thing would be:

```
    char c1, c2,            /* characters from each line */
        buf[MAXC] = "";     /* buffer to hold each line */
    ...
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))   /* read all chars */
        if (sscanf (buf, " %c, %c", &c1, &c2) == 2) { /* parse values */
            if (c1 > 0 || c2 > 0)   /* validate ASCII values */
                /* increment element in each */
                freq1[(unsigned char)c1]++, freq2[(unsigned char)c2]++;
        }
        else
            fputs ("error: in line format.\n", stderr);
```

**Handling the Frequency of Characters**

If you have been paying attention to the read of the data from the file, you will note that a pair of frequency arrays have been incremented on each read of the characters `freq1` and `freq2`. As mentioned in my comments above, you start with an adequately sized array of `int` to hold the ASCII character set. The arrays are initialized to zero. When you read a character from each column, you simply increment the value at:

```
        if (c1 > 0 || c2 > 0)   /* validate ASCII values */
            /* increment each element */
            freq1[(unsigned char)c1]++, freq2[(unsigned char)c2]++;
```

For example the ASCII value for `'a'` is `97` (see [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)). So if you read an `'a'` and increment

```
    freq1['a']++;
```

that is the same as incrementing:

```
    freq1[97]++;
```

When you are done with your read loop, you simply need to iterate over your frequency arrays from `'a'` to `'z'` and the number of times the corresponding character appeared in your file will be captured in your array. Then you can use the data however you like.

**Outputting The Results**

The simplest way to output your column1/column2 results is simply to output the number of occurrences for each character. For example:

```
    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)    /* loop over 'a' to 'z' */
        printf (" %c:  %d, %d\n", i, freq1[i], freq2[i]);
```

Which will produce output similar to:

```
$ ./bin/freq_dual_col2 <dat/char2col.txt
lowercase occurrence:

 a:  1, 1
 b:  1, 0
 c:  1, 1
 d:  1, 0
 e:  1, 1
 f:  1, 0
 ...
```

If you wanted to get a little more verbose and note whether the characters appears `"none"`, or `1` or whether the character was duplicated `"dupe"`, you could employ a few additional checks, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {  /* loop over 'a' to 'z' */
        if (freq1[i] == 1)              /* check col 1 chars */
            printf ("  %c , ", i);
        else if (!freq1[i])
            fputs ("none, ", stdout);
        else
            fputs ("dupe, ", stdout);
        if (freq2[i] == 1)              /* check col 2 chars */
            printf ("  %c\n", i);
        else if (!freq2[i])
            fputs ("none\n", stdout);
        else
            fputs ("dupe\n", stdout);
    }
```

Which would produce output as:

```
$ ./bin/freq_single_dual_col <dat/char2col.txt
lowercase single occurrence, none or dupe:

  a ,   a
  b , none
  c ,   c
  d , none
  e ,   e
  f , none
  ...
```

Putting it altogether, your minimal example using `fscanf` for your read could be similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAXC UCHAR_MAX+1

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char c1, c2;    /* characters from each line */
    int freq1[MAXC] = {0}, freq2[MAXC] = {0};   /* frequency arrays */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf (fp, " %c,%c", &c1, &c2) == 2)    /* read all chars */
        if (c1 > 0 || c2 > 0)   /* validate ASCII values */
            /* increment each element */
            freq1[(unsigned char)c1]++, freq2[(unsigned char)c2]++;   

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    puts ("lowercase occurrence:\n");
    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)    /* loop over 'a' to 'z' */
        printf (" %c:  %d, %d\n", i, freq1[i], freq2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The example using `fgets` and `sscanf` would be similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAXC UCHAR_MAX+1

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char c1, c2,            /* characters from each line */
        buf[MAXC] = "";     /* buffer to hold each line */
    int freq1[MAXC] = {0}, freq2[MAXC] = {0};   /* frequency arrays */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))   /* read each line */
        if (sscanf (buf, " %c, %c", &c1, &c2) == 2) { /* parse values */
            if (c1 > 0 || c2 > 0)   /* validate ASCII values */
                /* increment each element */
                freq1[(unsigned char)c1]++, freq2[(unsigned char)c2]++;   
        }
        else
            fputs ("error: in line format.\n", stderr);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    puts ("lowercase occurrence:\n");
    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)    /* loop over 'a' to 'z' */
        printf (" %c:  %d, %d\n", i, freq1[i], freq2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

And if you wanted the more verbose output, then I leave it to you to incorporate it in the code above.

Look things over and let me know if your have further questions.

Comment: `(int)` cast serves little purpose. `freq1[(int)c1]` is UB when `c1 < 0`.  Consider `freq1[(unsigned char)c1]` or `freq1[CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN + 1] = {0};  freq1[(int)c1- CHAR_MIN]`, etc.

Comment: Yes true. The cast was to prevent the `[-Wchar-subscripts]` warning, but we can tighten up with unsigned or non-overflowing type. Thanks. Wouldn't the conversion validations of `fscanf` and `sscanf` ensure that `c1/c2` were greater than `0`? It was a pickle using the `scanf` function to convert to `char` while not running afoul of the `[-Wchar-subscripts]` warning without intervening conversions.

Comment: There is nothing about `fscanf, sscanf` that insure `char c1 >= 0`. OTOH, `fgetc()` reads characters as `unsigned char`.  I think the warning of `-Wchar-subscripts` is valid and the cast `(int)` is the wrong solution.

Comment: I guess the best way to handle the concern would be an intervening check on `if (c1 < 0 || CHAR_MAX < c1) /* handle error */` as any other conversion to `char` would leave the same warning.

Comment: Yet `c1 < 0` is not an error. Just one of the (128) values that may be negative.

Comment: Although reading character value in the 0-127 is common, values in the -128 to 127 or  0 to 255 range are possible.

Comment: @chux I decided upon assignment to `int` and then validation within the positive range of `char`. Look over the update and let me know if there are holes there.

Comment: 1) `CHAR_MAX < i1` not possible.  2) The assignment to `int i1` is not needed. just skip the `freq1[...]++` with a negative index.  The way to deal with `-Wchar-subscripts` to use `unsigned char` or offset by `CHAR_MIN`.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting in the time to help me with an answer as in depth as this! I've learned more from this answer than searching for an hour did for me! thank you!

Comment: Your welcome, any time @chux takes an interest -- I usually do as well `:)`

Comment: Thank you @chux as well!

Answer (score 0):

Add all columns to Sets and check if the Sets are same size of file lines.

- remember that Sets ignore duplicates

Comment: This is tagged with `c` which doesn't have a type called `Sets`  Is it a third party library or are you thinking of C++?

Comment: I had not seen the tag. Sorry.